# How to change messenger language after adding it in website?

Tags: javascript, laravel, messenger

I have multiple languages in my site.I already added messenger using this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: 'my_app_id',
    autoLogAppEvents: !0,
    xfbml: !0,
    version: 'v3.0'
 })
 };
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return
}
js = d.createElement(s);
js.id = id;
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
```

Is it possible to change messenger language depending on my session local langugage ?

Comment: I assume the relevant part is the `en_US` in `js.src`? If so, just insert an appropriate language string into the URL.

Comment: ah yes as simple as that i'll just do an "if" depending on the language thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'my_app_id',
            autoLogAppEvents: !0,
            xfbml: !0,
            version: 'v3.0'
        })
    };
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        @if(Session::get('locale') == 'ar')
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/ar_AR/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
        @elseif(Session::get('locale') == 'fr')
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
        @elseif(Session::get('locale') == 'en')
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
        @endif
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
</script>
```